# perl what is the difference between the two scripts

Tags: perl

```
echo ab cd ef | perl -pe 'if($.==1){@L=split;foreach(@L)
{$_="SING.$_";}$_="@L\n"}'
SING.ab SING.cd SING.ef

echo ab cd ef | perl -pe 'if($.==1){@L=split;foreach(@L)  
{$_="SING.$_";}print"@L\n"}'
SING.ab SING.cd SING.ef
ab cd ef
```

What is `$_="@L\n"` doing? What does it mean? I suppose the first output is the output I want, but why can't I get it using the second code?

Comment: Please show what input you have, and what output you expect. Besides the actual issue you may be facing, take a peruse of [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `-p` flag to perl wraps your script in a loop:

```
LINE: while (<>) {
    … your script …
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

In other words: it reads each line into `$_`, runs your script, and prints `$_` afterwards. This is what your first script snippet is depending on.

Your second script prints something on its own, but that doesn't make Perl skip its own `print`, so it ends up printing the original value of `$_` afterwards. You can bypass this by using the `-n` flag instead of `-p` -- this behaves the same way, except without the automatic `print`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful!